# How to print IP/MASK from a list?

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I have a list with IPs and IP/MASK looks like:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
192.168.0.1
223.0.0.0/15
213.32.7.0/24
...
```

How can I only print IP/MASK line?
I used command `sed '/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}\/\d{1,2}$/p' list.txt`  but always print all the list. Thanks!

Comment: ``grep "/" list.txt``

Comment: @user996142 Please post your answer as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `\d` regex => `[0-9]` as sed doesn't understand it. And you need to invoke sed with the `-E` option to turn on extended regexes `{` in place of `\{`

```
sed -nEe '/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\/[0-9]{1,2}$/p'
```

Comment: I like this one, it explained why my regEX doesn't work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can grep for number, slash and number to match the netmasks, something like can do the work:

```
grep -o "\d\/\d"
```

or

```
grep -o "[0-9]\/[0-9]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just grep by slash `grep "/" list.txt`